# How to close an unclosed connection in Greenhill's multi debugger without rebooting my device?

Tags: greenhills

I have done it again, for the 7th time in the past hour I closed a multi debugger session without disconnecting from the device I was probing...

And now I cannot reconnect to the device because multi thinks the previous connection is still open.

> Port number 1 is higher than the total number of available ports: 0...

Besides rebooting the computer for the 100th time this day, is there another trick to make Greenhill's multi close the connection without rebooting my device?

(I am running multi 5.7 if that matters).